# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'method'

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a code to indicate the ratio between the mean and median when looking at some data about movies.

I then would like to add up these ratio's per category through an index but for some reason I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'method'
```

this is my code:

```
ratio_Production_Budget = abs((df_data['Production Budget'].mean() - df_data['Production Budget'].median()) / df_data['Production Budget'].median())
ratio_Worldwide_Gross = abs((df_data['Worldwide Gross'].mean() - df_data['Worldwide Gross'].median()) / df_data['Worldwide Gross'].median())
ratio_quarter = abs((df_data['quarter'].mean() - df_data['quarter'].median()) / df_data['quarter'].median())
ratio_duration = abs((df_data['duration'].mean() - df_data['duration'].median()) / df_data['duration'].median())
ratio_actor_1_facebook_likes = abs((df_data['actor_1_facebook_likes'].mean() - df_data['actor_1_facebook_likes'].median()) / df_data['actor_1_facebook_likes'].median())
ratio_imdb_score = abs((df_data['imdb_score'].mean() - df_data['imdb_score'].median()) / df_data['imdb_score'].median())
ratio_weekendTotal = abs((df_data['weekendTotal'].mean() - df_data['weekendTotal'].median()) / df_data['weekendTotal'].median)
ratio_midweekTotal = abs((df_data['midweekTotal'].mean() - df_data['midweekTotal'].median()) / df_data['midweekTotal'].median)

w1_mm = pd.Series(data= [ratio_Production_Budget, ration_Worldwide_Gross, ratio_quarter, ratio_duration, ratio_actor_1_facebook_likes, ratio_imdb_score, ratio_weekendTotal, ratio_midweekTotal],
                          index = ['Production Budget', 'Worldwide Gross', 'quarter', 'duration', 'actor_1_facebook_likes', 'imdb_score', 'weekendTotal', 'midweekTotal'])
```

Comment: Please clean up your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not a python guru, just looking at discrepancies I see. Do you need () on your weekendTotal and midweekTotal "last index" medians? I'm not sure how python plays with () - it can cause issues in other languages though.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote twice `median` instead of `median()`, so you get the methods (so the literal function) and not a function call.

You should learn to produce minimal code, and in such case, you will probably find yourself the problem.

Comment: @Aaron: Now you get it. I just quickly read your comment, and I was thinking you pointed to other errors (you cited the variables).